# Streamlit text_input displaying empty field with multiple pages

Tags: python, streamlit

In streamlit I have a display issue using a text_input.

##### Context

I want, with a text_input, to display a path stored in a .yaml file, and if changed in the text field in the app, to be updated in the yaml file.
For what I’m doing, I want this option to be available in 2 different pages.

##### Setup

For the example, I have three pages:

- A main page to start the app – that’s an empty page, but it is used to start the app with python (streamlit run Main_page.py)
- 2 pages (page1 and page2) to show the problem.

The code in page1 and 2 is the same, and is displayed below.
The steps are:

- Loading the content of the yaml file
- Creating the “test” key in the session_state if it does not exists
- Defining the callback function that check if the content of the yaml file is similar to the content of the sessions_state. If not, update the content of the yaml file, and save it.
- Creating the text_input, with the callbacl function and the test key.

```py
import streamlit as st
import yaml
from pathlib import Path

# Read the yaml file, and load the content
path_to_yaml= Path.cwd().parent / "path.yaml"    
contents = path_to_yaml.read_text()
yaml_content = yaml.safe_load(contents)

# Check if the test field is available in the session_state
if "test" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['test']=yaml_content["test"]

# Callback function when changing the value of the text field
def on_change():
    # Update the yaml file if different from the session_state
    if Path(yaml_content['test'])!=Path(st.session_state.test):
        yaml_content['test']=str(st.session_state.test)
        path_to_yaml.write_text(yaml.dump(yaml_content))

# Call the text_input function with the callback function and the "test" key
st.text_input( "Folder location to the parent file ", on_change=on_change(), key="test")
```

##### Behavior

After the command streamlit run Main_page.py is run, the app opens on the Main_page, then I click on the page1, and the text_input works fine with the correct value showing. Changing the value of the text input works as expected – the yaml file is correctly updated (show the screenshot below for visualization).

[image]

Now if I click on page2, the text_input is displaying nothing. If I go back on page1, the text_input shows nothing neither:

[image]

But if I click on the Main_page, then on page1 (or page2), then the text_input displays the correct value again…

##### Second Test

In page1.py and page2.py, I changed the text_input command

From this:

```py
st.text_input( "Folder location to the parent file ", on_change=on_change(), key="test")
```

to this:

```py
st.text_input( "Folder location to the parent file ", value=st.session_state.test, on_change=on_change(), key="test")
```